# Vector of functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an `attack(choice: number, enemy: Monster)` method, that must select between 3 different attacks based on the choice.

```
tackle(enemy: Monster){}
bite(enemy: Monster){}
laser(enemy: Monster){}
```

However, the implications of each method (Enemy dying, for example) is triplicate the way i'm current implementing it

```
if(choice == 1){
   bite(enemy);
   *
   *
   lines of bitting implications
   *
   * 
   *
}

else if(choice == 2){
   *
   *
   *
}
else {
  *
  *
  *
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to create an `attack_methods[3]`that allows me to simply implement

```
attack_methods[1] = tackle(enemy: Monster){};
attack_methods[2] = bite(enemy: Monster){};
attack_methods[3] = laser(enemy: Monster){};
```

and then

```
attack(choice: number, enemy: Monster, attack_methods[]: GodKnows){

     attack_methods[choice](Monster);
     *
     *
     *
     implications of choice
     *
     *  
     *

}
```

and, if it's possible, the proper way to implement it

(I used to program in c, I don't know much about typescript yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean way to have different implementation would be to have a map of choices and a function to be executed according to the choices.

For the sake of readability, I will change the type of `choice` from `number` to `string`.

Define all the choices like so:

```
const CHOICE_TACKLE: string = "TACKLE";
const CHOICE_BITE: string = "BITE";
const CHOICE_LASER: string = "LASER";
```

Define the functions like so:

```
const tackle = (enemy: Monstor) => { 
    /** Tackle implementation */
}

const bite = (enemy: Monstor) => { 
    /** Bite implementation */
}

const laser = (enemy: Monstor) => { 
    /** Laset implementation */
}
```

You can have them in different files and import them to one file as well.

Once you have all the choices and the implementation in place, you can define a map like so:

```
const ATTACK_IMPLEMENTATIONS = {
    [CHOICE_TACKLE]: tackle,
    [CHOICE_BITE]: bite,
    [CHOICE_LASER]: laser
}
```

And then your attach function would be:

```
const attack = (choice: string, enemy: IMonstor) => { 
    const attackFunction = ATTACK_IMPLEMENTATIONS[choice];

    if (!attackFunction) { 
        console.error(`No attach function implementation found for choice "${choice}"`);
        return;
    } 

    attackFunction(enemy);
}
```

---

Note that this is a simple way to make the code clean. For more advanced use cases, you might want to look at [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)